# How to get "word count" of a book?

Tags: webapp-rec, amazon

I came across [a thread in AskVille](http://askville.amazon.com/confirm-words-book-simply-counting/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=5790598) that claims we can get the word count of books on Amazon which have the "Look Inside" label.

Yet no matter how I search, I couldn't find the "Text Stats" link.

Did Amazon removed this feature?

Are there other web applications that give the "word count" of a book?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thread you refer to is 76 months old as of today (3/19/2014), dating that post to 2007.

It seems that the text stats feature was [removed at some time during 2012](http://blog.karenwoodward.org/2011/07/best-thing-since-sliced-bread-amazons.html).

Curiously, Amazon's help page [still mentions the text stats feature](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=10197041).

Hovering over the cover of *some** books with the "Look Inside" feature enabled will bring up a popup that offers some links. The "Text Stats" used to be here.

Unfortunately, this feature no longer seems to be available anywhere on the site.

[image]

<sup>*The author/publisher must opt-in for the [search inside feature to be enabled](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?ie=UTF8&nodeId=14061791).</sup>

Comment: What alternatives are there besides Amazon? I've heard that GoogleBooks insanely OCRed almost all available books on Earth, but "text stats" can't seem to be found there as well....

Comment: I haven't found anything comparable yet.

Answer (score 0):

For most books, you should be able to simply Google "Word count [book title]"  It usually comes up for me depending on the popularity of the title.

Answer (score -1):

I found a similar thread that gave an old URL that still works.

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/sitb-next/0060530626/ref=sbx_txt/002-2018152-0260852?_encoding=UTF8#textstats](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060530626)

I found that if you replace the product ID in the url you can still access the "text stats" page. I only tried it on two books but it worked on both so I thought I'd share.

In the above URL, replace the `0060530626` with the product id of the book your are looking for. To do this, find the book you want on amazon. Here's an example of one on amazon: www.amazon.com/How-Read-Book-Intelligent-Touchstone/dp/0671212095/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1417307816&sr=8-1

The ID here is the number after `/dp/`. So if I replace the id in the first url with the id of the book I want, I can see the word count of that book! :)

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/sitb-next/0671212095/ref=sbx_txt/002-2018152-0260852?_encoding=UTF8#textstats](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0671212095)

Not sure how long this trick will work, but someone might find it useful.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to work. For example, I tried itusing dp=0439139600 and dp=0470267585 but for both pages, the "text stats" doesn't appear.....